# Retain value of variable between different html files

Tags: javascript, html

Fairly new to Javascript.

Imagine I have a Javascript file: `Book.js`, inside which I just have some global variable: `var globalVar = 0;`

Imagine I also have two separate html files: A.html and B.html, both of which use above script: e.g. have   `<script src="src/model/Book.js"></script>` inside.

- Now, when I opened A.html I could see `globalVar` was defined. **Then I incremented is using console.**
- Then, when I opened page B.html, I was expecting `globalVar` to retain its value (since I declared it as global inside Book.js file and B.html also loaded Book.js) but it was undefined.

Is that expected?

**Does it mean scope of global variables is inside one html page?**

Apparently the second time the `Book.js` script got loaded, variables declared during previous invocation of Book.js "disappeared".

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly expected. The web would be a very chaotic place if every "global" variable from every page you ever visited was retained forever.

Comment: @deceze So it means you must use localStorage or something similar if you want to access variable declared in other page?

Comment: Yes - localStorage (or sessionStorage) is ideal for this.

Comment: every time you load a javascript file it get's back to the original state.
e.g. var x = 0; in the script and set x to 1 in console it will stay there until you unload the javascript file (simultaneously with the html file).

Comment: this is what cookies and later localStorage was made to handle

Comment: @KevinKloet I see if I load Javascript file for second time, it will start from a "fresh page" (meaning all state will be lost)

Comment: indeed the page will be back to the original state

Comment: thanks to all for feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that expected?

Yes

> Does it mean scope of global variables is inside one html page?

It is more akin to each page being a new program (and a reload of a page being akin to exiting the program and then running it again).

> So it means you must use localStorage or something similar if you want to access variable declared in other page?

Yes. That's why localStorage was created.

Comment: "It is more akin to each page being a new program" --> Ah, this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the Javascript is loading in one page and cannot be changed this way, because you are reloading it from your server. Basically, each page is a different process.

However, you can use a lot of workaround like :

- LocalStorage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- Cookie : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

And if you use a complex application, you can manage your gobal variable in back